# Django tag like input for a ManyToMany field in a model

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, tagging

Currently, I have an issue where within my model I have two ManyToMany fields that basically need to act like tags. I either need my data to go from my HTML to my view so I can populate it in the view function, or just have it work with some special form type.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
 ...
 skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
 interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest)
```

Where Skill and Interest are classes as follows

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    SKILLS = (
        ('0','Skill 1'),
        ('1', 'Skill 2'),
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SKILLS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Currently, my form does not pass in the skill or interest and I can get it to populate off checkboxes. But would like to make it a taggable sort of entry used in Bootstrap: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.